# Material UI Date Picker: Allow null or empty value when saving as timestamp to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui, datepicker

I am using the following in ReactJS:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
<MobileDatePicker
label={"Date From"}
inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
closeOnSelect={true}
value={datefrom}
minDate={new Date()}
views={['day']}
onChange={(newValue) => {
setDateFrom(format(newValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
if (dateto == '') {
setDateTo(format(newValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
}
}}
renderInput={(params) => <TextField variant="outlined" {...params} fullWidth />}
/>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I want to allow a null or empty date - but the record does not save and the console returns the error :

*Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value at Date.toISOString ()*

How do I allow a null or empty date - this field is being saved as a timestamp to Firebase.